# CakePHP composer Terminal flashes and disappears

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I have just installed CakePHP with Composer.

My problem is that when I try to run the terminal it just flashes and disappears. Has anybody ever encountered this issue and how have gone around it?

I am using XAMMP server.

Comment: I am using XAMMP server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open a command prompt:

   - <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
   - Input "**`cmd`**".
   - <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Chdir to your `app` directory:

   ```
   C:\Users\me> cd /path/to/cakephp/app
   ```
3. Run `cake`:

   ```
   C:\path\to\cakephp\app> bin/cake
   ```

See:

- Cookboox 3.x: [Code Generation with Bake](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html)

Comment: Thanks @Inigo Flores very helpful.